# How to overload a delegate function?

Tags: c#, delegates

I create a delegate for a logarithmic function that is then input into used as an argument of another function.  I want that logarithmic function to be capable of being used with one argument defaulting to log base 10 or two arguments where it changes the log base to the value of the second argument.

Currently I have

```
Func<double, double, double> pow = (x, y) => Math.Pow(x, y);
Func<double, double, double> log = (x, y) => Math.Log(x, y);
Func<double, double> log = x => Math.Log(x, 10);
Func<double, double> ln = x => Math.Log(x, Math.E);

var target = new Interpreter()
  .SetFunction("pow", pow)
  .SetFunction("ln", ln)
  .SetFunction("log", log);
```

With this I receive the following error:

```
A local variable or function named 'log' is already defined in this scope.
```

I understand WHY I get this error, it is pretty straight forward.  But I should be able to create a delegate function with multiple overloads, right?  I mean this is c# in 2018.  There must be another way I can achieve this.

I also tried the following to achieve the same.

```
Func<double, double?, double> log = (x, y) => Math.Log(x, y == null 
     || double.IsNaN(y.Value) 
     || (y > 0.0 - double.Epsilon && y < 0.0 + double.Epsilon)  ? 10 : y.Value);
```

But that only works if I explicitly define null for the second argument.  I want to be able to omit the second argument and it default to base 10.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that what you actually wanted were generics, not Delgates?

Comment: That Interpreter class is pretty broken.  It *really* cares whether a function takes 1 or 2 arguments.  There is no way to find out, so there is no way to make the right call.  SetFunction() needs one more argument, `numberOfArguments`.  Now you completely don't care that you have to name it "log10".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method overloading is based on the method *name*. Delegates do not have names, the fact that you have variables names is irrelevant. Moreover, a `Func<double, double>` is not the same as a `Func<double, double, double>` there are no overloads for generics.

So no, even though it is 2018 you cannot do this for a multitude of good reasons. You will need to create a custom class that can select between the "overloads" based on some condition (could certainly be the presence of an optional argument).

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to use a local function with an optional parameter for your base.

```
double log(double x, double y = 10.0) => Math.Log(x, y);
```